# How to intercept third party http request in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express

I need to call a third party API server in NodeJS, as you can see below, I need to use `req` and `resp` inside `request()` method.

Since there are a lot of APIs that I need to use, I don't want to `set headers` and `set response cookies` every time I use `request()`.

Is there anything I can do to intercept `request()`?

```
router.post('/register', function (req, resp) {
    var api = "/user/register"
    var data = req.body)
    request({
        url: api,
        method: "POST",
        json: true,
        headers: {'session_id' : req.cookies.session_id},
        body: {
            "tel": data.tel, "code": data.code,
            "password": data.passwd, "referee": data.recommend
        }
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        resp.cookies('session_id', response.headers['sessionId'])
        resp.json(body)
    })
})
```

Comment: `request` package doesn't know nothing about `express` and him `request` and `response` objects, so you can't intercept. But you can create two simple functions which will extract required info from `req` and update `res`. Just call these functions in every call of `request`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very elegant, but you could always create your own wrapper around request

e.g.

## myrequest.js

```
var request = require('request');

exports.postJsonWithCookie = function(url, payload, req, resp) {
  request({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    json: true,
    headers: {'session_id' : req.cookies.session_id},
    body: payload
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    resp.cookies('session_id', response.headers['sessionId'])
    resp.json(body)
  });
}
```

then in your route definition you could do

```
var request = require('./myrequest');

router.post('/register', function (req, resp) {
  var payload = {
    "tel": req.body.tel, 
    "code": req.body.code,
    "password": req.body.passwd, 
    "referee": req.body.recommend
  }
  request.postJsonWithCookie("/user/register", payload, req, resp);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to avoid passing the same options to `request` everytime?

You can simply create a helper function that will call it for you:

```
function apiRequest(url, req, cb) {
  request({
  url: url,
  method: "POST",
    json: true,
    headers: {'session_id' : req.cookies.session_id},
    body: {
        "tel": req.body.tel, "code": req.body.code,
        "password": req.body.passwd, "referee": req.body.recommend
    }
  }, cb)
}

// Your previous code becomes
router.post('/register', function (req, resp) {
  apiRequest("/user/register", req, function (err, response, body) {
    resp.cookies('session_id', response.headers['sessionId'])
    resp.json(body)
  })
});
```

Of course, it would be better if you added error handling to this (e.g. checking that `req` isn't undefined, that `req.body.X` exists, etc.)